# errors on gh-pages - nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a project in nuxt.js. I tried to deploy it on gh-pages doing npm install gh-pages --save-dev. I add some code to packed.json and was ok, a saw my project on gh-pages

https://aniaska4.github.io/business_card/

But suddenlly my project disapeared and I got an errors:

[image]

I have .nojekyll file in gh-pages branch, but the errors are still here.

I dont know why. Any hints to help?

**EDIT:**

For everybody who have the same problem. I used [travis-ci](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/github-pages/#travis-ci) to deploy my project once again. This is not only for node.js but for other as well.  Now it is ok.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to deploy only the content of the `dist` folder not the folder itself
2. You need to setup router base

nuxt.config.js

```js
export default {
  router: {
    base: '/<repository-name>/'
  }
}
```

See [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/github-pages)

Comment: so in branch `gh-pages` I create only dist folder and deploy it? Or remove gh-pages branch, create dist folder in master branch and only this folder deploy?

Comment: Don't create any `dist` folder in your `gh-pages` branch. Push the content of `dist` folder created by `npm run generate` into `gh-pages` branch...

Comment: Sorry to disturb you, but I still have a problem.. I create a new repository with only a dist folder.. it looks ok, https://github.com/aniaska4/starsWars, https://aniaska4.github.io/starsWars/ (there is still no pictures, I'll fix it). But I want to have all my code in github. I don,t know what am doing wrong. shame of me :/

Comment: ok so i did something and it works.. but for me there is still errors with code. In branch `gh-pages` I should have only `dist` folder. I added this `dist` folder manualy in githab, but then `githab` automatically did pull request and I have the same folders like in `master` branch :/ I suspose it is not good.. https://github.com/aniaska4/business_card

Comment: What is the documentation you are referring in your question ? (steps you were following)

Comment: You generally want to create `gh-pages` branch in very special way so it doesn't include your `master` branch files and history. Take a look [here](https://gist.github.com/ramnathv/2227408). Then remove `dist` folder from `master` and add it to `.gitignore` ...you don't want your build artifacts besides your source code...

Comment: yes, now I understand. I change everything and install `gh-pages --save-dev`. It was ok for a few minutes, but now still have a errors. It really makes me crazy :/ I edithed now my post and add what I did.

Comment: @anna did you check documentation? You can handle this easily with CI/CD. Check this https://nuxtjs.org/faq/github-pages/#travis-ci

Comment: Thank you for that. I used travis-ci in other project and it is ok. So now I will try in this case.